Notice: Undefined index: img_upload in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\магазин\application\ps.php on line 9
при нажатии кнопки выдаёт ошибки

Notice: Undefined index: img_upload in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\магазин\application\ps.php on line 9


Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\магазин\application\ps.php on line 9


Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\магазин\application\ps.php on line 9

Вот коды:
ps.php

    <?php
            session_start();
            include("db.php");
        
            if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $price = $_POST['price'];
                $info = $_POST['info'];
                $imgdir = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['img_upload']['tmp_name']));
                
                if (empty($img_dir)){
                    echo "Картинка не добавлена";
                } else {
                    
                    $query = "INSERT INTO merchendise (name, price, img_dir, info) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
                    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name, $price, $img_dir, $info);
                    
                    if ($stmt->execute()) {
                    //Обновление страницы после нажатия "Добавить"
                        header("Location: ../index.php");
                        exit(); // Завершение скрипта
                    } else {
                        echo "Ошибка при добавлении заметки: " . $stmt->error;
                    }
                    $stmt->close();
                }
            }


upload_product.php
<?php
    include("application/ps.php")
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form method="post" action="application/ps.php">
            <h1>Введите данные товара</h1>
            <div>
                <p>название</p>
                <input type="text" name="name">
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>цена</p>
                <input type="text" name="price">
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>добавьте изображение</p>
                <input type="file" name="img_upload">
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>описание</p>
                <input type="text" name="info">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Добавить">
        </form>    
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>


enctype="multipart/form-data" не мешало бы форме добавить

теперь появляется ошибка Column 'img_dir' cannot be null

Потому что Вы пытаетесь считать содержимое файла и сохранить его в БД, вместо того чтобы сохранить файл на сервере и записать к нему путь в базу.

@Simon в целом-то никто не запрещает грузить контент файла в БД. А вот $imgdir != $img_dir.

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?
